# How can i connect to a system in different lan?

Tags: networking, connection, ip

I am new to networking concepts. i know the basics of public and private ip. If two systems are in different LAN and i want to connect to one system from other and i need to send data. I've already tried with command line search, it will give only the private ip? Even if i know the public ip, how can i specify my destination system (there could be more than one system coming under the same public ip right?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to configure on router or firewall of the network where the ftp server is a NAT or a PAT, in order to map a public IP address to the private address that you obtain with the netstat command.

Over than this you have to configure firewall rules on the network of the ftp server to allow inbound ftp connection to the public ip address. You can restrict this connection for the public ip used by the client.

In the network where the client is, you have to allow the client to estabilish ftp connection with the public ip address of the ftp server. You have to do it on the firewall or the router of the client network.

It is not possible to give you more details about it, the detailed implementation depends on your network topology and network devices.

Regards
Giova

Comment: yes, public internet network, and protocol i need is ftp.?

Comment: i've just read about pat and nat, thanks for the info. I think i am looking for pat. if i am correct, then there is no need of private ip concept in pat?

Comment: "netstate -a" in destination system giving me a 10.x.x.x:yyyy --- i am sure this is a private ip. how can i use this info to communicate. :(